# MSCVR100.dll missing on EC2 Instance When Trying to Run NGINX

Tags: nginx, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, visual-c++

I'm trying to run NGINX with an RTMP module on an Amazon EC2 instance, but when I try to, I get an error message saying;

> The program can't start because MSCVR100.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem.

After doing some research I found that you need to install the correct windows redistributables, so I downloaded them from [Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=14632) (x64 as it is a 64 bit operating system) and installed them.

I've tried restarting the instance and tried to run NGINX but still get the same error. Does anyone know a solution for this?

Comment: Make sure you have both x86 and x64 Visual C++ installed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have installed the 32-bit version of NGINX, then you need the 32-bit version of
[Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package (x86)](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5555).

You should also assure that these are found in the PATH environment variable,
or alternatively copy the needed DLLs to the NGINX binary folder.

Comment: That's it! Installed the 32 bit version and NGINX ran as expected, thankyou.